# Error run mongod

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when run command "mongod" in terminal. Cant access localhost:28017

my log

```
2016-07-08T11:31:15.479-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12891 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=lucaspc
2016-07-08T11:31:15.479-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.7
2016-07-08T11:31:15.479-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 4249c1d2b5999ebbf1fdf3bc0e0e3b3ff5c0aaf2
2016-07-08T11:31:15.479-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-07-08T11:31:15.479-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-07-08T11:31:15.479-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-07-08T11:31:15.479-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-07-08T11:31:15.480-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-07-08T11:31:15.480-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-07-08T11:31:15.480-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-07-08T11:31:15.480-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-07-08T11:31:15.531-0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-07-08T11:31:15.531-0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2016-07-08T11:31:15.531-0300 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2016-07-08T11:31:15.531-0300 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a process using the interface and port you want to use.  You can find out what process that is using

```
sudo netstat -lpn | grep 27017
```

Then use

```
sudo kill <pid>
```

to stop it

Answer (score 0):

```
Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
```

You already have an instance running on port 27017, change the port or kill the existing process.